# How to make some actions (pages) in the controller accessed only by certain members ? (asp.net-MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

Alright so i made a login page and decorated all my actions with [Authorize] so only those who logged in can access it, now i  want some of the users ( The Admins ) to have access on certain actions ( pages).

my users table is as follows

```
userID , Username , password, name(idk why) , class ( 1 for normal users, 2 for admins )
```

so how im supposed to do it ?

Edit: if this makes it easier, its only one admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can use Authorize attribute, like  `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` or `[Authorize(Users = "John")]`. See example below:

```
[Authorize(Users = "John")]
public ActionResult Secret()
{
    return View();
}
```